# scala: optional default argument as function of other arguments

Tags: scala, constructor, default-value

I have a constructor, which takes one main argument (`data`), and another argument (`model`), that has a reasonable default initialization, which depends on the main argument.

I want to have the possibility to give another value for `model` whenever that's appropriate.

A simplified example:

1) without default arguments:

```
class trainer(data:Int,model:Double) {}
```

2) initialization:

```
def init(data:Int): Double = 1.0/data
```

3) it would work if initialization were independent of other arguments:

```
class trainer(data:Int, model:Double = init(1)) {}
```

4) what I would like to have, but what gives an error:

```
class trainer(data:Int, model:Double = init(data)) {}
```

What's the best/closest way to achieve what I want to do?

(my particular case deals with a constructor, but I would be interested whether there is a way in the general case for functions as well)

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no way to get default arguments in a function, at least not if you want to be able to represent the default behavior in the function's type so that it will work the same way even when used indirectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply have an overloaded constructor:

```
class Trainer(data:Int, model:Double) {
    def this(data:Int) = this(data, init(data))
}
```

Then you can instantiate using:

```
new Trainer(4)
new Trainer(4, 5.0)
```

Another approach is to use a companion object with different `apply` overloads:

```
//optionally make the constructor protected or private, so the only way to instantiate is using the companion object
class Trainer private(data:Int, model:Double)

object Trainer {
    def apply(data:Int, model:Double) = new Trainer(data, model)
    def apply(data:Int) = new Trainer(data, init(data))
}
```

Then you can instantiate using

```
Trainer(4)
Trainer(4, 5.0)
```

Another approach is to use an `Option` with a default of `None`, and then initialize a private variable in the class body:

```
class Trainer(data:Int, model:Option[Double] = None) {
    val modelValue = model.getOrElse(init(data))
}
```

Then you instantiate using:

```
new Trainer(5)
new Trainer(5, Some(4.0))
```

Comment: A companion object with an overloaded `apply` method could also add a nicer syntax. `def apply(data: Int, model: Double) = trainer(data, Some(model))`

Comment: The companion object with `apply` is really useful, as it allows us to create an instance Trainer only if some particular condition are met with the arguments. For example, we could return `None` if `data` is negative, or `Some(Trainer)` otherwise.